# Google OAuth2 API Separate Tokens by Subdomain

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

I have a multi-tenanted app that I need to integrate with a Google API endpoint, lets say the Calendar API.

The application is organized much like Slack. You can create a namespace and invite users to it. The subdomain is used to separate namespaces, so there could be: `foo.domain.com`, `bar.domain.com`, and `baz.domain.com`.

A user, can belong to multiple namespaces, much like in slack where you can belong to different teams. So `John` can be a member of both `foo` and `bar`.

The problem is, when `John` decides he wants to give `foo` access to his calendar info, Google links the authorization to `domain.com` rather than `foo.domain.com`. When I attempt to give access his calendar to `bar` as well, there is no refresh token because technically `John` has already authorized the access... but I would like these to be treated independent. So that `John` is able to revoke access to `foo.domain.com` but continue to have `bar.domain.com` access his calendar data.

Is there a way to create independent authorizations for the same user to the same app? I can't share the `refresh_token` across subdomains as they may be physically separated, and I can't create a different app for each subdomain as they are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way authentication works is that its based upon the client you created in Google developer console.

If John grants your client access to his calendar data then that client will have access to his calendar data.   Google has no way of knowing that its your foo or bar subdomains that have been granted access.

**Multiple client option**

You should probably created different client credentials for each of the different sub domains.   Thats probably going to be the most logical way of doing it.

**Single client option**

Besides doing that you could store the information in your database someplace John has granted access to foo but not bar and store the refresh token for foo but not for bar and if he wants to delete it for foo then he can do that.    You wont have to worry about keeping the refresh tokens updated as a user can technically have up to 50 refresh tokens associated with a single client.

Just watch it with revoke if the user does a revoke its going to revoke access to everything not just a single app.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer DaImTo... unfortunately I don't think either of those will work... I can't share the information (Single client option) as different subdomains may be physically separated and unable to communicate between, nor can I do the Multiple client option, since subdomains are created dynamically during signup and it doesn't seem as though I can generate those programatically :(

Comment: These are your only options really.   Its how Oauth works in general.   Users authenticate to a client.   I still think that the single client option could work if you set it up correctly in your databases.

Answer (score 0):

Google's OAuth implementation only returns a refresh token in the response if the user explicitly clicked the "Authorize" button. This always happens the first time the user is prompted for authorization, but by default the consent screen is skipped when the same application asks for authorization again for the same scopes.

You can override this behavior, and force the user to see the consent screen again by adding the parameter `prompt=consent` in your authorization URL:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#re-consent

Doing so will ensure that a refresh token is returned each time. Keep in mind that a given user-application pair can only have 50 refresh tokens active at a time, after which older tokens will be invalidated:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration